# fullcalendar events are always coming in All day event slot and how to edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii, fullcalendar

This is how data is passed.

```
$items[] = array(
        'title' => 'Meeting',
        'start' => strtotime('2014-09-09'),
        'color' => '#CC0000',
        'allDay' => true,
        'url' => 'http://anyurl.com'
    );
    $items[] = array(
        'title' => 'Meeting reminder',
        'start' => '2014-09-15 05:20:17',
        'end' => '2014-09-15 05:30:17',
        'color' => 'blue',
    );

    echo CJSON::encode($items);
    Yii::app()->end();
```

And another issue i have is when enable true as below, it says

```
'editable'=>'true',
'selectable' => true,
```

Property "EFullCalendar.editable" is not defined.
Property "EFullCalendar.selectable" is not defined.

Here is how it should work exactly, http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.1.1/demos/external-dragging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all events are being displayed as All Day, make sure that you don't have `allDayDefault` set to `true` ([take a look at the docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/)).

For your second issue, make sure `editable` is `true` (boolean instead of string). If it still doesn't work, please include the javascript where you set the default options for fullCalendar.